# Debug PHP processes started through `proc_open`

Tags: php, eclipse, phpunit, xdebug

I'm trying to debug PHP processes which were started through `proc_open`. This means the script code itself is passed as string through `fwrite`. E.g. by using PHPUnit with calls like this:

```
$php = \PHPUnit_Util_PHP::factory();
$response = $php->runJob("<?php\nrequire 'some/framework/bootstrap.php';");
```

You will find the regarding source code on [GitHub](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/master/src/Util/PHP/Default.php). As debugger I use currently Xdebug and as IDE Eclipse.

My settings for Xdebug look like this:

```
xdebug.remote_log=/tmp/xdebug.log
xdebug.idekey=ECLIPSE_DBGP
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_host=192.168.1.80
```

The problem is that no breakpoint is reached for these processes. When I take a look into the log (`/tmp/xdebug.log`) I see several [`init`](http://xdebug.org/docs-dbgp.php#connection-initialization) packets like this (exactly three after [`fclose($pipes[0]);`](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/master/src/Util/PHP/Default.php#L47)):

```
<init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1"
      xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" 
      fileuri="dbgp://stdin" 
      language="PHP" 
      protocol_version="1.0" 
      appid="2091" 
      idekey="ECLIPSE_DBGP">
  <engine version="2.2.5"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine>
  [...]
</init>
```

But Eclipse never response like it does for the parent process from the CLI (`../vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit -c [...]`):

```
<init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" 
      xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug"
      fileuri="file:///var/www/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit" 
      language="PHP" 
      protocol_version="1.0" 
      appid="2103" 
      idekey="ECLIPSE_DBGP">
   <engine version="2.2.5"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine>
   [...]
</init>
```

So the only difference between these both `init` packets is the attribute `fileuri`. It contains for the processes started through `proc_open` just a `dbgp://stdin`, which makes sense because these scripts came from a string.

**So my question is how can I get eclipse to respond to these initials with `fileuri="dbgp://stdin"` correctly?**

It seems Eclipse only responds when it receives an `init` packet with a `fileuri` it can map. But how would a mapping configuration look like for `dbgp://stdin`?

*Just to be clear, beside the processes started through `proc_open` is my set up totally fine and working. This means I'm able to debug scripts started through the CLI or my Browser.*

Answer (score 0):

I'm interested in this as well.

I use PHPStorm and the IDE would halt debugging at exactly the place you mention inside PHPUnit. PHPStorm would complain that it was unable to map a file named `/<path-to-file>/-`. I was able to get it to work by copying the PHP script string that was passed in the call to `fwrite()`, save that as a file somewhere locally, and then using map the path `/<path-to-file>/-` to the file I saved locally. After that PHPStorm would carry on debugging through that.

I imagine something similar could work in Eclipse.